# built in equals method in Java

Tags: java

I have the Following code in Java:

```
class Complex {
    private double re, im;

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Complex c1 = new Complex(10, 15);
        Complex c2 = new Complex(10, 15);
        if (c1.equals(c2)) {
            System.out.println("Equal ");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Not Equal ");
        }
    }
}
```

My question:
why this program outputs Not Equal?, So the build-in equals method is used for content comparison, and not for adress comparison like == operator.
tnx a lot :)

Comment: You haven't overridden `equals` in your class.

Comment: What do you mean by "*built-in*"?  The one inherited from `Object` class?

Comment: So, if I dont override the equals method, it not should compare the contents of the objects?

Comment: if you don't override it, the Object method is used: `return (this == obj);` Documentation: " The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true)."

Answer (score 1):

If you haven’t overridden the equals() method in your class, it refers to the equals method in the base class ‘Object’.
The default implementation of equals in Object class is a shallow comparison of object references(addresses).

Comment: So you mean in this case there is no difference between the non-overriden equals method and the == operator?

Comment: That is what `Object.equals(Object)` does so if you don't override it, it will use `==` only.

Comment: You can see [the default implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#l148) simply delegates to `==`. One difference to note is that `equals` will throw an NPE if the first object is `null`. But yeah, if you want to have a useful `equals`, you should override it.